# Decode constructor arguments in solidity

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

I playing Ethernaut Level 8. The goal is to get access to the private password state variable and unlock the contract.

I know one could use `await contract.unlock(await web3.eth.getStorageAt(contract.address, 1));`, but I want to find the password decoding the input data of the contract creation. [Here](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xc7552dadcb06ff5edf056375d72b886b704b9941) is the contract.

I tried `await contract.unlock("f94b476063b6379a3c8b6c836efb8b3e10ede188")` but that didn't work.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract Vault {
  bool public locked;
  bytes32 private password;

  constructor(bytes32 _password) public {
    locked = true;
    password = _password;
  }

  function unlock(bytes32 _password) public {
    if (password == _password) {
      locked = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the contract is verified, it is possible to go to the [contract section](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xc7552dadcb06ff5edf056375d72b886b704b9941#code), scroll down to *Contract Creation Code* and read the last 32 bytes (64 characters of the bytecode) which in this case is `0x412076657279207374726f6e67207365637265742070617373776f7264203a29`.

> it is 32 bytes because the password state variable is declared like this:
>
> `bytes32 private password;`

To solve the challenge type:

```
await contract.unlock("0x412076657279207374726f6e67207365637265742070617373776f7264203a29")
```

Comment: I think something worth to add is why we are taking 64 characters and not 32.

The bytecode is the hexadecimal representation of the Solidity code, remember that a byte is a set of 8 bits and a single hex is represented by 4 bits (2^4 = 16). So that means that a byte in this hexadecimal representation is composed by 2 characters (4 bits + 4 bits = 8 bits = 1 byte)

Since the password variable is bytes32 (8 bits (byte) * 32 = 4 bits (hex) * 64).